# Advantages of using drupal mobile technology over mobile middlewares

Tags: 7

This is a very serious question that every one asks. I have a drupal website now which is not mobile ready. I will tell the scenario. We gave a demo to client of kurogo, which we modified to show content from drupal website. So 1st question was, whats the benefit of this over creating mobile ready themes with in drupal. So my question is, will there be any extra benefit of using external mobile middle ware like Kurogo, then developing drupal mobile themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do everything in Drupal. My recommendation is to run an m.site.com domain (either to a different multi-site or with branching logic in settings.php) that not only changes to a mobile theme, but also switches to an alternative anonymous page cache bucket and sets a few variables for later use.

Then, whether you are using panels or not, you can set ctools page_manager overrides for your homepage, content listings, node views etc. and have these only kick in for the mobile domain. This way you can potentially hit the database less for logged in users by showing simple pages, and you can also switch imagecache/'image styles' to be more appropriate to the device and save on bandwidth.

That way you can get all the output you'd get from Diazo or Kurogo but keep it all in Drupal. Which is you are working in a team of Drupallers, is surely a good thing

Hopefully that little ramble described the approach well enough to be useful ;)

I think the http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools module contains ways of doing this if you don't know how to write it yourself.